# How to use a variable for a table name when running a For Loop within an Oracle pl/sql email send

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I am unable to complile this section of Oracle code as the compiler reports "PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist"

The Oracle table exists but this procedure must pass a table name to the For Loop procedure based on the "Order_ID" parameter. I am working within the Schema where the table exists so I am not addressing a schema name.

Example: TEMP_TBL_123 exists in the database and by passing the order_ID of 123 I am attempting to use variable TMP_TBL_NM to hold the table name "TEMP_TBL_123".

.................................................

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE EMAIL_DEPT_BLAST_TEST (SUBJECT VARCHAR2,MAIL_FROM VARCHAR2, MAIL_TO VARCHAR2,
                                               L_MESSAGE VARCHAR2, L_MESSAGE2 VARCHAR2, ORDER_ID NUMBER)
IS
MAIL_HOST VARCHAR2(30):='XX.XX.XX.XX';
MAIL_CONN UTL_SMTP.CONNECTION;
TMP_TBL_NM VARCHAR2(30);

BEGIN

TMP_TBL_NM := 'TEMP_TBL_' || ORDER_ID;

MAIL_CONN := UTL_SMTP.OPEN_CONNECTION(MAIL_HOST, 25);
UTL_SMTP.HELO(MAIL_CONN, MAIL_HOST);
UTL_SMTP.MAIL(MAIL_CONN,'XXX@XXXXXX.com');
UTL_SMTP.RCPT(MAIL_CONN, MAIL_TO);
UTL_SMTP.OPEN_DATA(MAIL_CONN);
UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(MAIL_CONN, 'Date: '||to_char(trunc(SYSDATE))||utl_tcp.crlf);
UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(MAIL_CONN, 'From: '|| mail_from ||utl_tcp.crlf);
UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(MAIL_CONN, 'To: '|| mail_to || utl_tcp.crlf);
UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(MAIL_CONN, 'Subject: '||subject||utl_tcp.crlf);
UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(MAIL_CONN, UTL_TCP.CRLF);
UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(MAIL_CONN, ''|| L_MESSAGE || UTL_TCP.CRLF);
UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(MAIL_CONN, UTL_TCP.CRLF);

UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(MAIL_CONN, 'Order details:' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(MAIL_CONN, 'Quantity - Location ID - Address' || UTL_TCP.crlf);

BEGIN
    FOR I IN (SELECT LOCATION_ID, TRIM(TO_CHAR(COUNT(*),'9,999')) AS QUANTITY FROM TMP_TBL_NM GROUP BY LOCATION_ID)
    LOOP 
    UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(MAIL_CONN, I.QUANTITY  || ' - ');
    UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(MAIL_CONN, I.LOCATION_ID || ' ');
    UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(MAIL_CONN,UTL_TCP.CRLF);
    END LOOP;
END;

UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(MAIL_CONN, L_MESSAGE2 || UTL_TCP.CRLF);  

UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(MAIL_CONN,UTL_TCP.CRLF);
UTL_SMTP.CLOSE_DATA(MAIL_CONN);
UTL_SMTP.QUIT(MAIL_CONN);

END SCT_CNTS_EMAIL_DEPT_BLAST_TEST;
```

Answer (score 5):

I didn't have much luck making John's example work. Here's something that does:

```
DECLARE
    C SYS_REFCURSOR;
    stmt VARCHAR2(1000); 
    tmp_tbl_nm  VARCHAR2(64) := 'USER_TABLES';
    the_name    VARCHAR2(64);
BEGIN
    stmt := 'SELECT table_name  FROM ' || TMP_TBL_NM || ' ORDER BY 1';
    OPEN C FOR stmt;
    LOOP
      FETCH C INTO the_name;
      EXIT WHEN C%NOTFOUND;
      dbms_output.put_line(the_name);
    END LOOP;
END;
/
CONTINENT
COUNTRY
COUNTRYINFOIMPORT
COUNTRY_LANGUAGE
GEONAME
LANGUAGE

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

I don't think you can return a cursor with an EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement. [This documentation page,](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/dynamic.htm#i13130) second paragraph, seems to indicate not. At any rate, you don't need it, just use the OPEN - FOR syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you get the PL/SQL: ORA-00942 is because in your original code the compiler is looking for a table called "TMP_TBL_NM". This doesn't exist in your schema and is really a variable holding the name of the table within your PL/SQL.

I took the liberty of adapting a previous answer and used a bit of dynamic SQL to come up with a variation for your answer.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE EMAIL_DEPT_BLAST_TEST (SUBJECT VARCHAR2,MAIL_FROM VARCHAR2, MAIL_TO VARCHAR2,
                                               L_MESSAGE VARCHAR2, L_MESSAGE2 VARCHAR2, ORDER_ID NUMBER)
IS
MAIL_HOST VARCHAR2(30):='XX.XX.XX.XX';
MAIL_CONN UTL_SMTP.CONNECTION;
TMP_TBL_NM VARCHAR2(30);

BEGIN

TMP_TBL_NM := 'TEMP_TBL_' || ORDER_ID;

MAIL_CONN := UTL_SMTP.OPEN_CONNECTION(MAIL_HOST, 25);
UTL_SMTP.HELO(MAIL_CONN, MAIL_HOST);
UTL_SMTP.MAIL(MAIL_CONN,'XXX@XXXXXX.com');
UTL_SMTP.RCPT(MAIL_CONN, MAIL_TO);
UTL_SMTP.OPEN_DATA(MAIL_CONN);
UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(MAIL_CONN, 'Date: '||to_char(trunc(SYSDATE))||utl_tcp.crlf);
UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(MAIL_CONN, 'From: '|| mail_from ||utl_tcp.crlf);
UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(MAIL_CONN, 'To: '|| mail_to || utl_tcp.crlf);
UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(MAIL_CONN, 'Subject: '||subject||utl_tcp.crlf);
UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(MAIL_CONN, UTL_TCP.CRLF);
UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(MAIL_CONN, ''|| L_MESSAGE || UTL_TCP.CRLF);
UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(MAIL_CONN, UTL_TCP.CRLF);

UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(MAIL_CONN, 'Order details:' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(MAIL_CONN, 'Quantity - Location ID - Address' || UTL_TCP.crlf);

TYPE ItemRec IS RECORD (
loc_id NUMBER,
qty_cnt NUMBER);

TYPE ItemSet IS TABLE OF ItemRec;
all_items ItemSet;

BEGIN

    stmt := 'SELECT LOCATION_ID, TRIM(TO_CHAR(COUNT(*),'9,999')) AS QUANTITY FROM '||TMP_TBL_NM ||' GROUP BY LOCATION_ID';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt
    BULK COLLECT
    INTO all_items;

    FOR i IN all_items.FIRST..all_items.LAST
    LOOP
        UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(MAIL_CONN, I.QUANTITY  || ' - ');
        UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(MAIL_CONN, I.LOCATION_ID || ' ');
        UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(MAIL_CONN,UTL_TCP.CRLF);
    END LOOP;
END;

UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(MAIL_CONN, L_MESSAGE2 || UTL_TCP.CRLF);  

UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(MAIL_CONN,UTL_TCP.CRLF);
UTL_SMTP.CLOSE_DATA(MAIL_CONN);
UTL_SMTP.QUIT(MAIL_CONN);

END SCT_CNTS_EMAIL_DEPT_BLAST_TEST;
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to pass variables into SQL statements like this would be to run the query as [dynamic sql](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg09dyn.htm).

Your code might be something like:

```
DECLARE
    query_output SYS_REFCURSOR;
    query_statement VARCHAR2(1000); 
BEGIN
    query_statement := 'SELECT LOCATION_ID, TRIM(TO_CHAR(COUNT(*),'9,999')) AS QUANTITY FROM ' || TMP_TBL_NM || ' GROUP BY LOCATION_ID';
    execute immediate query_statement using out query_output;
    ....
END
```

Now that you have a cursor, fetch the contents, loop over the count and do everything else

Comment: "only way to pass variables .. would be .. dynamic sql".  Not really true.  A PL/SQL variable can be embedded into an inline SQL statement anywhere you might otherwise put a literal value, such as a string or a number.  What you can't do, without dynamic sql, is use a variable in place of an *identifer*, such as a table name or column name.  This is because identifier names must be known when the SQL statement is parsed, which occurs before variable values are bound.